# Thanos Ruler Query Config Bearer for Oauth based API not working

Tags: oauth-2.0, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, thanos

I'm using Thanos Ruler and trying to add a an API based query url to its configuration.
Referring from the Thanos Official docs of building Thanos Ruler (https://thanos.io/tip/components/rule.md/#query-api), we configured the oauth based token access via a Configmap in the below format.

```
- http_config:
    bearer_token: "<oauth-token>"
  static_configs: ["<query API>"]
  scheme: https
```

As per our requirement, we were able to fetch the Bearer Token and add to this configmap after every scheduled interval.
Thanos Ruler tries to reach the querier but always returned with response:
"no query API server reachable".

Can anyone pls explain me where I'm doing it wrong. Also it would be great, if you can provide some sample configurations to refer to.

Comment: Hi, anyone answer?